# Elevate user for uninstall wix installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uninstallation, silent-installer

I'm working on wix installer. There I have given option to user to install it for per machine(all user) and per user.

If I'm using the below code:

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallPrivileges="elevated" InstallScope="perMachine" />
```

everything is working fine for per machine(all user). User is able to install and uninstall properly but installer is not working for per user.

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes"/> if use this code
```

installation is working fine for both per machine and per user.
but uninstall is not working for per machine. once we say run as admin, its properly uninstall it.

so question is how to elevate the user during uninstall so that it work in both scenario per machine(All user) and per user.

Comment: It would help if you said what "uninstall is not working" means. Error messages? A custom action failure?

Comment: It's coming out from bootstraper.  not getting any proper exception.just saying roll back from bootstraper.please help

Comment: During installation there is one custom action to which we are elevating like impersonate =no,execute=deffered then selecting per machine for installation. Error is coming like installscope is per user not per machine. I think this is problem. Wix expert please help

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Hi Stein:  please use this  <Package InstallerVersion="301" Compressed="yes" InstallPrivileges="elevated"/> to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

to elevate the user for install/uninstall use the following code which work for both per user and per machine

```
 <Package InstallerVersion="301" Compressed="yes" InstallPrivileges="elevated"/>
```